# How to get the TitledBorder's title to display properly in the GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have the GUI displaying properly for the most part, except for one thing.  The TitledBorder("Numeric Type") does not display the entire title for the right JPanel.  I believe it has something to do with the BorderLayout Manager.  Instead of displaying "Numeric Type" within the border, just "Numeric..." displays.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class P3GUI extends JFrame {

    private JLabel originalList;
    private JTextField originalSort;
    private JLabel sortedList;
    private JTextField newSort;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton performSort;
    private JRadioButton ascending;
    private JRadioButton descending;
    private ButtonGroup sort;
    private JRadioButton integer;
    private JRadioButton fraction;
    private ButtonGroup numType;
    private JPanel inputPanel, outputPanel, calculatePanel, radioPanel;
    private JPanel left, right;

    public P3GUI () {
        super("Binary Search Tree Sort");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        originalList = new JLabel("Original List");
        originalSort = new JTextField(20);        
        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.add(originalList);
        inputPanel.add(originalSort);
        sortedList = new JLabel("Sorted List");
        newSort = new JTextField(20);
        newSort.setEditable(false);
        outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.add(sortedList);
        outputPanel.add(newSort);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(inputPanel);
        panel.add(outputPanel);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        performSort = new JButton("Perform Sort");
        calculatePanel = new JPanel();
        calculatePanel.add(performSort);
        add(calculatePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
        ascending = new JRadioButton("Ascending");
        descending = new JRadioButton("Descending");
        sort = new ButtonGroup();
        sort.add(ascending);
        sort.add(descending);
        integer = new JRadioButton("Integer");
        fraction = new JRadioButton("Fraction");
        numType = new ButtonGroup();
        numType.add(integer);
        numType.add(fraction);
        radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        left.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Sort Order"));
        left.add(ascending);
        left.add(descending);
        right = new JPanel();
        right.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Numeric Type"));
        right.add(integer);
        right.add(fraction);
        radioPanel.add(left);
        radioPanel.add(right);
        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        pack();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new P3GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the right `JPanel` is too small to display the entire title, and so it gets truncated. I'd suggest placing the bottom two JPanels into another that uses `GridLayout`, and then place them in such a way that they expand to fit the bottom of your GUI. When spread out, the title has a much greater chance of being fully displayed (but not a guarantee, mind you!).

For example, if you make the main GUI use a `BorderLayout`, and add this `GridLayout` using `JPanel` into the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, it will fill it completely. Then the top components, the `TextField`s and `JButton` can be added to another `JPanel`, say one that uses a `GridBagLayout`, and add that to the main `JPanel`'s `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` position.

For example, the following code produces this GUI:

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class P3GUI2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 20;
    private JTextField originalSort = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextField newSort = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JButton performSort = new JButton("Perform Sort");
    private JRadioButton ascending = new JRadioButton("Ascending");
    private JRadioButton descending = new JRadioButton("Descending");
    private ButtonGroup sort = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton integer = new JRadioButton("Integer");
    private JRadioButton fraction = new JRadioButton("Fraction");
    private ButtonGroup numType = new ButtonGroup();

    public P3GUI2() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Original List:"), createGbc(0, 0));
        topPanel.add(originalSort, createGbc(1, 0));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Sorted List:"), createGbc(0, 1));
        topPanel.add(newSort, createGbc(1, 1));

        performSort.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(performSort);

        JPanel sortOrderPanel = createTitlePanel("Sort Order");
        JPanel numericPanel = createTitlePanel("Numeric Type");

        sortOrderPanel.add(ascending);
        sortOrderPanel.add(descending);
        sort.add(ascending);
        sort.add(descending);

        numericPanel.add(integer);
        numericPanel.add(fraction);
        numType.add(integer);
        numType.add(fraction);

        JPanel radioPanels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 3));
        radioPanels.add(sortOrderPanel);
        radioPanels.add(numericPanel);        

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(radioPanels, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel(String title) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return panel;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        P3GUI2 mainPanel = new P3GUI2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Binary Search Tree Sort");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Or you could place the above btnPanel into the main one `BorderLayout.CENTER` and then place the radioPanels into the main one `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. This will display a GUI of the same appearance but it will expand differently if re-sized.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred size of the panel (as determined by the layout manager) does not consider the size of the text in the `TitledBorder` so the title can get truncated.

Here is a custom JPanel that can be used with a TitleBorder. The `getPreferredSize()` method has been customized to use the maximum width of:

1. the default getPreferredSize() calculation
2. the width of the text in the TitledBorder

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TitledBorderPanel extends JPanel
{
    /**
     ** The preferred width on the panel must consider the width of the text
     ** used on the TitledBorder
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        Dimension preferredSize = super.getPreferredSize();

        Border border = getBorder();
        int borderWidth = 0;

        if (border instanceof TitledBorder)
        {
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            TitledBorder titledBorder = (TitledBorder)border;
            borderWidth = titledBorder.getMinimumSize(this).width + insets.left + insets.right;
        }

        int preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredSize.width, borderWidth);

        return new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredSize.height);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new TitledBorderPanel();
        panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("File Options Command List:") );
        panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        panel.add( new JLabel("Open") );
        panel.add( new JLabel("Close") );
//      panel.add( new JLabel("A really wierd file option longer than border title") );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TitledBorderPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```